# download csv file

Tags: php

we have a button when we click on that button all data come into csv file and download this csv file. 
csv file create but download code not working

```
$fp = fopen("file\customer-list.csv", "w");
fileName = "file\customer-list.csv";
$filePath = "file\customer-list.csv";
$fsize = filesize("file\customer-list.csv");

if(($_POST['csv_download_list']) == "cm")
{
    fwrite($fp, $csv);
    fclose($fp); 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    $file = @fopen($filePath,"rb");
    if ($file) {
        while(!feof($file)) {
            print(fread($file, 1024*8));
            flush();
        }
    @fclose($file);
}
exit;
```

Comment: why do you have so many variables lukin' around in your file. anyways.. i think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487774/generating-csv-file-and-then-forcing-the-file-to-download should solve your problem.

Comment: optionally you can also check out.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: If there is an acceptable answer, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Use this snippet should do what you are trying to do.

```
<?php

    $file = 'sample.csv'; //path to the file on disk

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        //set appropriate headers
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();

        //read the file from disk and output the content.
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to save the file to the disk, just echo the csv content after setting the appropriate header. 
Try the code below, it will be much simpler

```
$fileName = 'customer-list.csv';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

echo $csv;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try...
function download($file) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            return false;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit();
    }
$file = "file.csv";
download($file);
```